# How can I rename a syslog file

Tags: linux

How can I rename a syslog file, for example from `test.log` to `test2.log`, running on Linux server?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need rename the log file, you just need to log rotate. Check `/etc/logrotate.conf` file more info.